# Odd result using loop inside child method in C

Tags: c, for-loop, fork, parent-child, fibonacci

I am trying to print out the Fobonacci sequence according to how many numbers of it the user would like. I.e. if the user inputs 5, the output will be 1,1,2,3,5. So I setup a loop in just a normal C program to do this:

```
for(int m=1; m<=a;m++)
   {
     i = (pow(c, m)-(pow(v, m)))/b;
     printf("%d\n",(int)round(i));
   }
```

This for loop gives me the desired output I am looking for. But, when I put it into a child process of the fork method, the output changes. I.e. if the user inputs 5, the output will be 1,0,2,2,5. Why is this? and is there a way to fix it? Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <math.h>

int var_glb; /* A global variable*/

int main(void)
{
    pid_t childPID;
    double a;
    double c = 1.6180339;
    double v = -0.6190339;
    double b = 2.236067977;
    int i;


    childPID = fork();

    if(childPID >= 0) // fork was successful
    {
        if(childPID == 0) // child process
        {
            printf("\nEnter the first value:");
            scanf("%lf", &a);
            for(int m=1; m<=a;m++)
            {
                i = (pow(c, m)-(pow(v, m)))/b;
                printf("%d\n",(int)round(i));
            }
        }
        else //Parent process
        {
            wait(NULL);

            printf("\nThis is the parent process running");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else // fork failed
    {
        printf("\n Fork failed, quitting!!!!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to compute the Fibonacci numbers.  In fact, you should almost never use floating point arithmetic to compute something that can be expressed in pure integer arithmetic for both, correctness and performance.  Try `double fib = (pow(c, m) - pow(v, m)) / b; printf("%f\n", fib);` to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by fixing your brackets: `i = (pow(c, m)-pow(v, m))/b;` Also You cannot expect `i` to be `int`... `i` should be `float` or `double`

Comment: And that's the issue: the result is truncated to an integer when that expression is assigned to variable `i`.  It needs to be rounded instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to forking.  The program produces exactly the same result if all the forking is commented out, and everything runs in the parent process.  Apparently the algorithm is incorrect in some way.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the problem was that i declared the variable i as an int instead of a double, as I had did in another application, thanks for you help though, I will definitely use all of your suggestions to strengthen my code.